# If the limit of $1-(1-1/x)^x$ equals $1-1/e$, does this mean that only $63.21\%$ of possible things ever happen?

Tags: probability

$1-(1-\frac1x)^x$ is the analytic function modelling an ever-growing lottery where the number of attempts at the lottery correspond to the chance of winning said lottery; eg playing a $100$-ticket lottery $100$ times only gives the chance of winning at least once to be $1-(1-\frac1{100})^{100} = 63.4\%$, not $100\%$. As $x$ increases, the chance goes to $1-1/e$. At the limit, eg: infinitely many darts whose summed width corresponds to the area of the dartboard, this means that in an infinitely large universe, not everything possible actually gets to happen since the distribution is not uniform.

Follow up question, what does this distribution look like? Some things happen more than once. How would you calculate how many times the most-frequent outcome happens based on the size of $x$, and at the limit?

Comment: N.b. one should be careful about whether the hypotheses apply---different phenomena follow different distributions---but I suspect you're looking for the Poisson distribution. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution

Comment: If $p(n, m)$ is the probability of winning an $n$-ticket lottery in no more than $m$ times, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} p(n, n)$ is not the same as $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\lim_{m\to\infty} p(n, m)\right)$.

Comment: @anomaly, my question is regarding winning an n-ticket lottery in no more than n times.

Answer (score 1):

Your different attempts have to be independent for this theory to apply.

For instance you play 100 different 100-ticket lotteries.

Or you play a lottery where they pick the numbers out for you at random.

Then yes, playing 100 independent times with a 1/100 chance of winning gives you a probability of winning of 1-1/e$ \approx 63 $ %.

But you can go further. Play 200 times. Then the probability of winning is $1-e^{-2} \approx 90$ %. And so on.

Comment: For a lottery that is played 200 times, then the lottery would be 'bigger' at a 200-ticket lottery instead of a 100-ticket one. The number of tickets in the lottery exactly equal the number of attempts at it. Interestingly enough, even if you did get to play twice as much as the number of ticket in the lottery, the result is still less than 100% of lottery participants getting to win. Which would still be consistent with the original question Title regarding how not everything possible gets to actually happen. For everything possible to happen reminds me of the coupon collector's problem.